# Angular chat application distribution (server app) to the server

Tags: socket.io, chat, angular5

I am new to Angular

I followed the following tutorial [(Creating a Realtime App with Angular and Socket.io)](https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-socket-io-tutorial/)

Locally this works fine.

I can only install client part of this application by 'ng build --prod' and 
copy dist folder contents to the server.

But I have no idea of how to distribute the server part of this application as it is just a .js file to be run on port 5000

Help me to run this .js file in iis server

Comment: Looking at that tutorial, your server code is a node app. You'll need to use something like iisnode to get your node app to run in IIS. Here a more recent blog showing how to do that: https://www.simplymigrate.com/2017/04/11/internet-information-server-iis-node-js-in-producton-iisnode/

Comment: I installed node js and it worked. But azure url is problamatic as they use shared IP. I am trying to do a port forwarding